# HTML text-direction regarding arabic content. Is using dir="rtl" really mandatory?

Tags: html, arabic, right-to-left

First of all sorry for this perhaps silly question. But I'm trying to figure out if the `<dir="rtl">` attribute really is mandatory when displaying arabic characaters on a web page.

I've searched for a while now on this subject but I'm still puzzled. The W3C website states: "If a document contains right-to-left characters, and if the user agent displays these characters, the user agent must use the bidirectional algorithm." Source: https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/dirlang.html

As far as I understand the above text this means that you will have to use `<dir="rtl">` attribute but I can't find out why exactly.

The reason I'd like to know is that we have to create a 'somewhat' arabic version of a page without spending too much time on aligning and mirroring the whole website.

Does somebody know why the `<dir="rtl">` attribute is mandatory? Or why it maybe why it is not mandatory? The more I read about it the more it starts messing with my head and I have a hard time finding a clear answer.

Kind regards,
Jan-Willem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is mandatory because; 1. Its makes bots and users know how what language your page uses. 2. Its would display the text according to how that language is expected to be, **rtl** is mearnt for arabic and/or hebrews.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I particularly forgot about the bots and screen readers that also should be able to scan a page correctly. I stumbled across this page that explains more about why rtl should be used: https://www.w3.org/International/articles/inline-bidi-markup/uba-basics.

Comment: To be more precise, the base direction is the concept that explains the need of the rtl attribute: https://www.w3.org/International/articles/inline-bidi-markup/uba-basics#context